# RCA 6.4: What is this "contradiction"?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

The above image is the proof that claims any total variation of complex measure is bounded. The problem is I don't think this author has proved anything yet. If I understand it right:

We got sequence of disjoint subsets $A_i$, each measured by $|\mu|$is bounded under by 1. Take the terms to be $|\mu|(A_i)$ the series will diverge.
Then put $A = \cup_{i}{A_i}$ , by axioms of $\sigma$ algebra $A$ is also measurable set, measured $\infty$ by $|\mu|$. But we also have decreasing sequence of sets $B_i = X-\cup_{k\leq i}{A_k} $ Thus put $B=\cap_{i}{B_i}$, again is measurable by $|\mu|$ and it diverges.

Such construction of particular sets $A,B$ is nothing logically suspicious but where does this "contradiction(see in the last line of the proof)" come from?

Comment: Nevermind. I noticed that the thing of whole process was to show existence of a set $A$ that measured by $\mu$ is $\infty$ not by its variation, which leads me to nowhere but evident inequality. Since "complex measure" must have its range in complex plane, each complex values of measured sets must be finite and that's all, I was careless when reading definitions.

Comment: You can make that an answer itself, and then accept it after two days. :) See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center.